# Detect if range is empty

Tags: excel, vba, range

I want to check if a range in Excel is empty.

How do I write in VBA code:

```
If Range("A38":"P38") is empty
```

Comment: Consult the API (this is the PIA, but the COM which is used in VBA should be similar): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_members.aspx (the Count property, perhaps)

Comment: I'm pretty new to VBA so this don't make a lot of sense to me :)

Comment: `Range("A38:P38").Count`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139976%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Found a solution from the comments I got.

```
Sub TestIsEmpty()
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A38:P38")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Empty"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Empty"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Attention: **"Empty()"**  isn't a valid procedure Name. @darren-bartrup-cook, my proposed edit doesn't deviate from the original intent of the post and preserve its goals.

Comment: If there is a possibility that the range can contain empty string values (constants) or formulas that could return an empty-string value, and cells with empty-string values must be treated as "empty" then use this expression instead: WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("A38:P38")) = Range("A38:P38").Cells.Count
(And maybe use a With statement to clean it up.)

Answer (score 9):

If you find yourself in a situation where you can’t use `CountA` then it's much faster to first store your range as an array and loop on the array's data than it is to individually loop on range/cell data.

```
Function IsRangeEmpty(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean
    
    ''Returns true if a value is found in parameter range.
    ''Converts parameter range to an array to check it quickly.
    
    'if range has cells in it then
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    
        Dim area As Range
        For Each area In rng.Areas 'checks through all sub-ranges within the original range e.g., rng=Range("A1:B5,C6:D9")
            
            'if sub-range has more than one cell then
            If area.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            
                'save range as array
                Dim arr As Variant
                arr = area.value
                
                'loop through array
                Dim arrCell As Variant
                For Each arrCell In arr
                
                    'if cell is not empty then
                    If Len(Trim(arrCell)) > 0 Then
                        IsRangeEmpty = False
                        Exit Function
                    End If
    
                Next arrCell
                
            Else 'unnecessary to loop on a single cell
                
                'if cell is not empty then
                If Len(Trim(area.Value2)) > 0 Then
                    IsRangeEmpty = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
                
            End If
    
        Next area
    End If
    
    IsRangeEmpty = True

End Function
```

---

Example of how to use it:

```
Sub debug_IsRangeEmpty()
    Debug.Print IsRangeEmpty(Range("A38:P38"))
End Sub
```

If `Range("A38:P38")` is empty, it would print `True` in the Immediate Window.

Comment: To deal with the case when the range is only one cell, you can use "If rng.Cells.Count < 2 Then ..." and only test this cell.

Comment: @LePatay thanks for the heads up, I hadn't tested with just one cell! Should be fixed now.

Comment: This is absolutely something that should be a function! Perfect, thanks :)

Comment: The example in my comment to Kano's post above, is a simpler way to address this issue.

Comment: @pstraton looks like it matches DJK's solution

Comment: @Marcucciboy2: yes, technically, but part of my point was to provide a plug-compatible alternative in Kano's syntax.

Comment: You should also add a check for ` If Not rng Is Nothing Then`

Answer (score 5):

IsEmpty returns True if the variable is uninitialized, or is explicitly set to Empty; otherwise, it returns False. False is always returned if expression contains more than one variable. IsEmpty only returns meaningful information for variants. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx) . So you must check every cell in range separately:

```
    Dim thisColumn as Byte, thisRow as Byte

    For thisColumn = 1 To 5
        For ThisRow = 1 To 6
             If IsEmpty(Cells(thisRow, thisColumn)) = False Then
                 GoTo RangeIsNotEmpty
             End If
        Next thisRow
    Next thisColumn
    ...........
    RangeIsNotEmpty:
```

Of course here are more code than in solution with CountA function which count not empty cells, but GoTo can interupt loops if at least one not empty cell is found and do your code faster especially if range is large and you need to detect this case. Also this code for me is easier to understand what it is doing, than with Excel CountA function which is not VBA function.

Comment: Excel macro code (don't know if compiling is possible) takes a while when you have large number of iterations. Your solution is needed if you have already determined that some cell in the range is not empty and you want to process it, but the check of determining if a range is empty (ie, if your code is even necessary) should be faster and maybe much faster using the accepted answer (CountA). Using a single "native" function to a VB loop that does the same tends to lead to faster running times.

Comment: this doesn't always work. For instance if you have a range that is not a continuous selection after a selection (lets say your range selection skips 1 cell then it skips 5 cells, goes back to 1 cell, etc,,)  then this will error out.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim M As Range

    Set M = Selection

If application.CountIf(M, "<>0") < 2 Then
    MsgBox "Nothing selected, please select first BOM or Next BOM"
Else

'Your code here

End If
```

From experience I just learned you could do:

```
If Selection.Rows.Count < 2 
Then End If`
```

Clarification to be provided a bit later (right now I'm working)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you also provide a bit of clarification what the comparison is really doing for future visitors? EDIT: Also a bit tricky to understand how your edit fits in with the original example.

Comment: @Thor when you search for a solution to the problem on Google, you get this page. But this page doesn't answer that problem which is why i answered that problem. I believe people here don't just up-vote things. I can see this already helped a few people.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett sadly yes, every single hour of my wakeful life... Look, this helps to the one that seeks. I know that when i was trying to figure this out i came across this page, over and over in google search. This was exactly the solution i was looking for, so i tried to help others out and post it. Even if it isn't a 100% direct help, it's 1000% indirect help.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim cel As Range, hasNoData As Boolean

    hasNoData = True
    For Each cel In Selection
        hasNoData = hasNoData And IsEmpty(cel)
    Next
```

This will return `True` if no cells in `Selection` contains any data. For a specific range, just substitute  `RANGE(...)` for `Selection`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution. Count empty cells and subtract that value from the total number of cells

```
Sub Emptys()

Dim r As range
Dim totalCells As Integer

'My range To check'
Set r = ActiveSheet.range("A1:B5")

'Check for filled cells'
totalCells = r.Count- WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(r)


If totalCells = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Range is empty"
Else
    MsgBox "Range is not empty"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This just a slight addition to `@TomM's` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177273)/ A simple function to check
if your Selection's cells are empty

```
Public Function CheckIfSelectionIsEmpty() As Boolean
   Dim emptySelection As Boolean:emptySelection=True
   Dim cell As Range
   For Each cell In Selection
       emptySelection = emptySelection And isEmpty(cell)
       If emptySelection = False Then
          Exit For
       End If
   Next
   CheckIfSelectionIsEmpty = emptySelection
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This single line works better imho:

```
Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(E10:E14<>""""))=0")
```

in this case, it evaluates if range E10:E14 is empty.