# Detect if range is empty and return index of non-empty rows

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a VBA code to check if a Range in Excel is empty and, if not, what are the rows which are non-empty.
This question [10811121](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811121/excel-visual-basic-detect-if-range-is-empty) answers how to check if `Range("A1:L1000")` is empty:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:L1000"))
```

If the Range is not empty I would like to determine the indexes of the non-empty rows. It doesn't not matter how many cells are non-empty in the row. 
One solution is to check one by one if each row in the range is empty or not but I would like to know if there is an easier solution without looping.

Comment: What's not easy about looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) to quickly find all non-formula, populated values in your range.

```
set rng = Range("A1:L1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstant)
```

Comment: Thank @Jepped that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would loop.  The code is simple:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim i As Long, msg As String

   For i = 1 To 1000
      If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & i & ":L" & i)) > 0 Then
         msg = msg & "," & i
      End If
   Next i

   MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** have a problem with looping:

```
Dim vResult

Dim sFormula              As String

With Range("A1:L1000")
    sFormula = "IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(" & .Address & ",ROW(" & .Address & ")-MIN(ROW(" & .Address & _
               ")),0,1))>0,ROW(" & .Address & "),""|"")"
End With
Debug.Print sFormula

vResult = Filter(Application.Transpose(Evaluate(sFormula)), "|", False)
```

Comment: Hi Rory this is impressive, I tried to figured out how this formula works but for me it is pure magic :)