# Is empty is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I m writing a program and it is not working. 
I will write a simple version of it

```
Dim rng as range
Dim message as integer 
Set rng = Range(cells(1,1), cells (4,1))
If isempty(rng) then
   mess = msgbox ("hello", vbyesno, "hello")
      If mess = 6 then
       Msgbox "hello"
       Else
       Msgbox "bye"
       End if
Else
    Msgbox "haha"
End if
```

This is the program, 
But when the cell is empty or if there is a value in the cell then it executes the else statement, that is "haha" and howsoever doesn't execute the first statement although it may be true.
Why is it happening and what am i possibly doing wrong while writing the program.

Comment: Try `isempty(rng.value)`

Comment: Nope the same result

Comment: Do you want to test if ***all*** the cells in the range are empty or if ***any*** of the cells in the range are empty ???

Comment: If there are two different ways for them then please tell me both. Anyways mine to see if any one of the cell is empty or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Visual Basic - detect if range is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811121/excel-visual-basic-detect-if-range-is-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsEmpty` is not an Excel-specific function that detects empty cells.
It's a part of the VB6/A language and it checks if the variable of type `Variant` contains a special value, `Empty`.

It happens to work when checking contents of a *single* Excel cell because the expression `IsEmpty(cell)` [is understood as](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200523/11683) `IsEmpty(cell.Value)`, and `cell.Value` of a single cell returns a single `Variant` that may have the special value of `Empty` which `IsEmpty` detects.

In other cases it does not work:

- When you pass a multicell range to `IsEmpty`, the `range.Value` returns an array of `Variant`s. An array itself is never `Empty`, even when all its elements contain `Empty`.
- When you pass a `Range` variable that is `Nothing`, `IsEmpty` cannot detect it either, because `Empty` is not `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CountA` to see how many cells in a certain range are not empty.

`CountA` documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838049.aspx)

```
Option Explicit

Sub checkEmptyRange()

Dim Rng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1") '<-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(4, 1))
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng) > 0 Then
        If MsgBox("hello", vbYesNo, "hello") = vbYes Then
           MsgBox "hello"
        Else
           MsgBox "bye"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "haha"
    End If
End With    

End Sub
```