# Why is Isblank() in excel formulas and Isempty() in vba showing different values?

Tags: excel, vba

Based on this spreadsheet,

[image]

Running this line of code will return `False`

```
MsgBox IsEmpty(Trim(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(31, 1)))
```

But running

```
=IsBlank(A31)
```

will return `True`

Comment: Empty cells are empty and blank cells can appear empty although they aren't due to them containing a formula returning empty text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use `Trim`.

Excel's `IsBlank` is very restrictive and will only ever give True if the cell is completely empty (not even has a formula that returns empty result). So if that returns `True`, `IsEmpty` on the cell's value should also return True.

But what `IsEmpty(cell)` [actually does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43424424/11683) is detecting whether the `cell`'s `.Value` contains the special value `Variant/Empty`. The raw cell value does indeed contain it, and `IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(31, 1))` would return True, but `Trim()` turns the `Variant/Empty` into a `Variant/String`, and a string is never `IsEmpty`, even when it's zero length.

If for you "empty" means "contains zero length content", then you should check for `Len(Trim(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(31, 1))) = 0`.