# Is there any way to shorten down this IsEmpty() and Range statement in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to shorten down this line with a better range statement? When one cell out of the range `("C3:I3")` is empty I need it to produce a MsgBox, else run the rest of the code.

```vb
If IsEmpty(Range("C3")) = True Or IsEmpty(Range("D3")) = True Or IsEmpty(Range("E3")) = True Or IsEmpty(Range("F3")) = True Or IsEmpty(Range("G3")) = True Or IsEmpty(Range("H3")) = True Or IsEmpty(Range("I3")) = True Then
```

When I use `If IsEmpty(Range("C3:I3")) = True Then` the code behaves differently and does not work when only one cell is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if range is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10811121/11683)

Comment: For the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10811619/11683), replace the `= 0` with `= Range("C3:I3").Cells.Count`. For the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38055198/11683), replace the `= False` with `= True`.

Comment: Yes, I did already find this answer but was unable to make it work. I will try your alterations.

Comment: Your comment helped thank you, I realised that ```WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C3:I3")) < 7 Then``` would work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function IsRangeEmpty(ByRef theRange As Range) As Boolean
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In theRange
        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
            IsRangeEmpty = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next c
    IsRangeEmpty = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could any of the below:

**Loop range**:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rng = .Range("C3:C13")

        For Each cell In rng
            If cell = "" Then
                MsgBox "Empty cell!"
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

**Pass the range to an array and loop array - Faster:**

```
Sub test_1()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        arr = .Range("C3:C13")

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i, 1) = "" Then
                MsgBox "Empty cell!"
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```