# If length of cell is greater than 0, then do X

Tags: excel, vba

How may I tweak the following code to say If the length of cell (using Len formula) is greater than zero, then do X.

Currently, it's checking whether the cell is blank, however my cells have formulas so the current code is returning "false positives"

```
If Cells(7, 10).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in Unit Price (Row 1)"
    Checker = True
    End If
```

Comment: Make sure the formula are returning `""` and not `" "` with a space.

Comment: `If Len(Cells(7, 10).Value) > 0 Then`

Comment: Confirmed! I double checked the formulas and ran a CTRL+F to be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
If Len( Cells(7, 10).Value) > 0 Then
```

Comment: Thanks Luigi, how would it work if wanted a range instead? I'm using "If Len(Range("G7:O7").Value) > 1 Then" and it throws an error

Comment: There is an answer here: [detect-if-range-is-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811121/detect-if-range-is-empty)

Comment: @HashmatHabibzadah - A range is a series of values, so basically you deal with values present in several cells. You should therefore summarise those values in one number, for example taking the sum or the average, then you transform into a value. If you want to take into consideration each cell of the loop, you can do a loop, where you evaluate each single value of the range and you specific a behavior for this. Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not (IsNull(Cells(7, 10))) then
```

should work either

Comment: IsNull(cell) is False for any cell.