# Checking destination sheet for data before copying

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the following code which copies data from sheet1 and pastes it into Sheet2 via a command button, which is working fine with one problem.
Is there a way that VBA can check first to see if the destination sheet. sheet2 cells V8 to DM88 has already got data in it and if so not execute the code.
any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Col

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString

    Msg = "Do you want to continue ?"            ' Define message.
    Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2 ' Define buttons.
    Title = "Warning, This Action Canot be undone Once Accepted!  " ' Define title.
    'Help = "DEMO.HLP"    ' Define Help file.
    Ctxt = 1000                                  ' Define topic context.
    ' Display message.
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)
    
    If Response = vbYes Then                     ' User chose Yes.
        MyString = "Yes"                         ' Perform some action.
    Else                                         ' User chose No.
        MyString = "No"                          ' Perform some action.
    End If

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b11:cs88").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("v11")
    Range("b11:cs88").ClearContents
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps this is of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811121/detect-if-range-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the range is not empty (or empty, depends on your approach :) ). I would do it the first thing to save some time. If the range is not empty, then it will give a message and stop the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("V8:DM88")) <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Destination range is not empty"
    Exit Sub
End If
End If

    Msg = "Do you want to continue ?"            ' Define message.
    Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2 ' Define buttons.
    Title = "Warning, This Action Canot be undone Once Accepted!  " ' Define title.
    'Help = "DEMO.HLP"    ' Define Help file.
    Ctxt = 1000                                  ' Define topic context.
    ' Display message.
    Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)
    
    If Response = vbYes Then                     ' User chose Yes.
        MyString = "Yes"                         ' Perform some action.
    Else                                         ' User chose No.
        MyString = "No"                          ' Perform some action.
    End If

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b11:cs88").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("v11")
    Range("b11:cs88").ClearContents
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this but i am getting an error "438 object doesnt support this object or method on this line  "If Worksheets("Sheet2").WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("V11:DM88")) <> 0 Then"  thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry. I misplaced the sheet reference. It should only be before the range.

Comment: That is excellent, thank you so much its working well.

Comment: Thank you, please feel free mark the answer as accepted (grey ticker below voting buttons). Happy coding :)!!

Comment: Sorry I cant find how to accept you answer there is nothing below the Vote buttons